# Pre-allocation of attributes by creating new entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

While creating new entity in CRM, some fields will be pre-allocated. Exmaple:  for a new contact - transactioncurrency and ownerid will be filled with values. Haw can I programmatically find out, which rules will be used for such pre-allocation. I can't call "initializefromrequest" to find it out, because I want to build offline DB and there apply the rules

thanks

Comment: If your question is answered can you please mark it so. StackOverflow works by rewarding other people for finding solutions to your problems ;)

Answer (score 0):

Get the `EntityMetadata` for your entity then examine `AttributeMetadata` for each `Attribute` to determine if the `IsCustomAttribute` Property is `true`

1. [Retrieve Entity metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.retrieveentityrequest.aspx) using [`EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.entityfilters.aspx)
2. Iterate the [`Attribute` collection of the `EntityMetadata`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.entitymetadata_members.aspx) in the response
3. Check the `IsCustomAttribute` property on each `AttributeMetadata`